# Python crashing when trying to add <video> tag to a Webkit widget

Tags: python, html, webview, webkit, gtk2

I'm trying to do some program in Python 2.7 - 32 bit (Windows 7) with GTK2+Webkit. I executed the demo code and everything works fine: I create a HBox and fill it with a webcam input and a Webkit WebView. The WebView later shows some text, being updated when the camera input does something.

The problem comes when I try to insert a  tag in the WebView. Instantly the program crashes with a Windows error screen and no more information is shown in the command line (where I execute python file.py).

To add the  tag I use the following syntax:

```
gobject.idle_add(self.webview.load_html_string, "<video src=\"test.mp4\" controls></video", "file:///")
```

I tried using avi & mp4 files but all of them crashes.

The program also crashes if I try to add an  tag.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: No error, just "python.exe stopped working" in a Windows dialog.